# PHP OSX XAMPP - exec mount command

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp

Good Afternoon,
I am currently working on a PHP project which requires a php script to mount a windows shared drive.  Currently building using OSX with XAMPP.

```
exec('mount -t smbfs //user:pass@192.168.1.1/Share /Volumes/Share 2> temp/error.txt');
```

Now i understand why this does not work.  Its due to permissions.  Apache is running as user daemon.  Now i could change the user that Apache runs to fix this "challenge" but want to avoid any changes to the server if possible.
I would like to reach out and see if there is a better way to go about this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you not it outside of PHP and just keep it mounted?

Comment: because it is only required to be mounted for a short time before being unmounted.

Comment: Yes, but allowing a webserver user to mount it is probably a horrible idea, whereas mounting it in the system has less of a downside unless its hugely problematic for the SMB server. What type of machine is this going to run on when its deployed?

Comment: End of the day, multi platform is the aim.  I also looked at maybe doing a sudo but that probably is a horrible idea as well.  I don't want to leave the drive mounted as there could by any amount of shares that this project requires at any given time and things would just get messy.  Hence, a way for PHP to mount, run the required script and unmount the drive.

Comment: If you don't want to change the server then the only option would be to change the drive permissions. Add the Apache user to the drive's permissions?

Guh, even typing that sounds like a horrible idea. I would never want an open apache user to have user access to one of my drives 0_o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So i got it working.
I just needed the web server (user daemon) to own a folder in which the share is mounted.

EG. created a folder called "tempshare" that user daemon owns and is in the same folder as the php script (don't worry, it will be placed out of the web root when complete)

```
exec('mount -t smbfs //user:pass@192.168.1.1/Share /path/to/tempshare 2> temp/error.txt');
```

Seemed to work.  Any advice on security using this method?

Comment: I also found [munkie/samba](https://github.com/munkie/samba) BTW.. its a PHP SMB Client and corresponding stream wrapper. It does make use of `smbclient` though so its only for *nix systems and it would probably be a bit of work to add a Windows implementation... then again who runs PHP on a Windows box ;-) I did test it out and have example code if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks @prodigitalson! I'll have a look at it!

Comment: Also if you are going to be playing with it you will need to install `samba` with homebrew or `samba3` with macports since the client in OS X is `smbutil` and is different. (I tested with macports `samba3`).