# get file name from another computer with ip address

Tags: php, file, glob

I tried it in local and it succeed, now I want to get my file's name with ip address that another computer has shared.

This is working in local :

```
foreach (glob("C://xampp/htdocs/Champion/machine-logs/LogCampusMesinMutoh/*.job")as $job) {
```

This is executed from another computer and does not works :

```
foreach (glob("file://192.168.1.13/Job/*.job")as $job) {
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php: _“Note: This function will not work on remote files as the file to be examined must be accessible via the server's filesystem.”_

Comment: How does that share work in the first place? It's shared using what?

Comment: shared folder, i tried access to file://192.168.1.13/Job/, and it opened. so i write the address to my code.

Comment: I suppose that means SMB? Then: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28482053/476